# Supersized and Zurb's Foundation 5: slides are unclickable

Tags: zurb-foundation, supersized

://50.22.11.18/~luxuryvi/

I have some success pairing Supersized 3.2.7 and Zurb's Foundation 5 except that the supersized background images are unclickable despite the "url:" parameter in the call.

I know it may have been the z-index being a negative number and lower than everything else but I am just wondering if anyone happens to have seen a fix or perhaps manage to get round the issue.

Any info is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the url, a numeric domain is not allowed here but I would have no way to show my codes

Comment: its under maintenance, so i cant see the code.